# Multiple Versions of Firebase Installed - Which Do I Use?

Tags: firebase, npm, firebase-cli

I'm trying to build an app with Firebase and ran a few commands to see which version I have. To follow along with a 2021 instruction video, I was hoping to have Firebase v9. Depending on the command that I run, I somehow have versions 8 and 11. If I have these two versions, which one is actually being used? What is the difference between seemingly having an npm firebase and non-npm firebase installed?

```
armadillo@armadillo-MacBook-Air my-app % npm firebase --version
8.11.0
armadillo@armadillo-MacBook-Air my-app % firebase -V
11.2.2
```

Answer (score 3):

As covered by [@Doug](https://stackoverflow.com/users/807126)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73000505/3068190), the `firebase` command is defined by the `firebase-tools` npm package (or by https://firebase.tools if installed that way) not the `firebase` package, which does not define any command line utilities.

Additionally, `npm --version` returns the version of `npm` you have installed. This includes if you add the name of a package there. (i.e. `npm thisCouldBeAnythingNotANPMCommand --version` will return the same result)

If you want to view the version of a *deployed* package, you would use one of the following commands to query NPM's database:

```
npm view firebase version      (view package's "version" field)
npm v firebase version         (view package's "version" field, using shorthand)
npm view firebase              (get all available package information)
```

If you want to view the version of a package *installed* in your project or globally, you would use:

```
npm ls firebase                (local install)
npm ls -g firebase-tools       (global install)
```

If you want to view the where the npm-installed commands are, you would use:

```
npm bin                        (local install)
npm bin -g                     (global install)
```

For the `firebase` command, the `firebase`/`firebase.cmd`/`firebase.ps1` files all point to `<global bin directory>/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/bin/firebase.js`.

Compare the results of:

```
> npm v firebase version
9.9.0
> npm ls firebase
`-- firebase@9.0.0-beta.6      (an old project directory for another SO answer)
> npm v firebase-tools version
11.2.2
> npm ls -g firebase-tools
`-- firebase-tools@9.21.0      (updated since :D)
> npm --version
6.4.12
> npm firebase --version
6.4.12
> npm v npm version
8.14.0                         (updated since :D)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to work with the Firebase CLI, you should be looking at the [firebase-tools](https://www.npmjs.com/package/firebase-tools) npm package, not [firebase](https://www.npmjs.com/package/firebase).  They are definitely not the same thing.

```
npm firebase-tools --version
```

I suggest reviewing the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli) as well.